# Testing postMessage with Jasmine async doesn't work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, postmessage

I'm trying to use Jasmine 2.0 to write unit tests for some logic in an AngularJS app, but the logic is inside an event listener. From the controller:

```
  window.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
    if (e.data === "sendMessage()") {
      $scope.submit();
    }
  }, false);
```

And from the test file:

```
  describe("post message", function() {
    beforeEach(function(done) {
      var controller = createController(controllerParams);
      spyOn($scope, 'submit');
      window.postMessage('sendMessage()', '*');
      done();
    });

    it('should submit on a sent message', function (done) {
      expect($scope.submit).toHaveBeenCalled();
      done();
    });
  });
```

But the test fails, the spy never being hit. Extra info from putting in console debug statements:

- `window.addEventListener` in the controller IS getting called.
- The `beforeEach` and `it` block are both getting called.
- The above message handler in the controller is not getting called during the test.
- The message sent in this test is eventually being receievd by the message handler, several times, but not until after the test ends.

What is my test missing here?

Comment: Aren't you supposed to call postMessage on *another* window than the one that will receive the event ? (say, creating a popup, as is done on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2Fwindow.postMessage )

Comment: Tried changing it to a postmessage from a popup off of window instead of a postmessage from window, but all that changed is that, instead of receiving the message too late, it doesn't receive the message at all.

Comment: @AlanGordon: Did you already find a solution for this? I'm having the same issues ;-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is happening because in your `beforeEach` block you call `window.postMessage()` (which is asynchronous and you don't know when it's gonna execute) and then you call `done()` right after it as it would be synchronous code. But `window.postMessage()` as async, and basically you need to call `done()` when your async operation is complete. It could be done like this:

```
beforeEach(function(done) {  
    spyOn(someObject, 'submit').and.callFake(function () {
      done();
    });
});
```

So when your spy executes, then async operation is considered complete.

This could be expressed even shorter:

```
beforeEach(function(done) {  
    spyOn(someObject, 'submit').and.callFake(done);
});
```

Here is the full code:

```
var someObject = {
  submit: function () {
    console.log('Submit');
  }
};

window.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
  if (e.data === "sendMessage()") {
    someObject.submit();
  }
}, false);

// Test

describe('window.postMessage', function () {

  beforeEach(function(done) {  
    spyOn(someObject, 'submit').and.callFake(function () {
      done();
    });
    window.postMessage('sendMessage()', '*');
  });

  it('should submit on a sent message', function () {
    expect(someObject.submit).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });

});
```

See a working JS Bin: http://jsbin.com/xikewogagu/1/edit?html,js,console,output

I did not use Angular in this sample because it is reproducible with a pure JS.

Comment: Anyone knows why this works only if the spy and postMessage are inside beforeEach? If we wrap it inside `it("...", (done) => {})` will not work....

Comment: I think I got it. Putting `expect(...).toHaveBeenCalled()` inside `and.fakeCall` callback did it. Not sure if it's correct.