# asynchronous test jasmine timeout error

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, jasmine

I have read and tried different things for doing an asynchronous test in jasmine without any success.
[jasmine: Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22604644/jasmine-async-callback-was-not-invoked-within-timeout-specified-by-jasmine-defa)

[Testing window.postMessage directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30939566/testing-window-postmessage-directive)

[Testing postMessage with Jasmine async doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30788380/testing-postmessage-with-jasmine-async-doesnt-work)

I have the following code and i'm receiving the follow output.

> Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by
>   jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL

```
    describe('asynchronous tests', function () {
        var value;

        beforeEach(function (done) {
            spyOn(myService.$rootScope, '$broadcast').and.callFake(function(){
                done();
            });
            window.parent.postMessage({message:'event'}, '*');
        });

        it('Should support async execution test preparation and expectation', function(){
            expect(myService.$rootScope.$broadcast).toHaveBeenCalled();
        });
    });
```

myService is defined in the parent describe function. As I understand my beforeEach should wait until the postMessage is thrown before continuing the execution but I'm getting that timeout error.

Thanks

Comment: You need to pass `done`: `describe('asynchronous tests', function(done){`and I would move whole `beforeEach ` code (`spyOn` and `window.parent`) to `it` as there is only one test.

Comment: I can't add done to the describe I will get a "describe does not expect a done parameter" error

Comment: You should not have such error. See: https://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Asynchronous_Support

Comment: I know that's the reason why I'm asking this :)

Comment: Ay, my mistake. It should be passed to `it`, not to `describe`. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I simplified my test. I used the eventDispatcher to trigger manually the event that my service is listening and forgetting about window.postMessage(). The reason is what I'm testing is the service not the communication, so it doesn't matter how the event comes.

```
it('my test', function(){
    var event = new CustomEvent('message');
    event.origin = 'http://localhost:33333';
    event.data = {message: 'eventData'};
    spyOn(myService.$rootScope, '$broadcast');
    myService.subscribeEvent();
    window.dispatchEvent(event);
    expect(myService.$rootScope.$broadcast).toHaveBeenCalledWith('eventData',undefined);
});
```